# Custom pop up message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've looked around and haven't found anything that would work for my particular situation - is it possible to create a script that would display a custom pop up message in Google Spreadsheets when a particular cell has been changed.

ie. if C3, C5, C12 or C13 have been changed, an alert will pop up that G3 now has to be updated.

I'm not particularly skilled at custom scripts in google docs, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hook this up to an onEdit() in your ScriptEditors Edit/Current Project triggers menu.

```
function customPopUp(e)
{
  var myCellsA=['C3','C5','C12','C13'];
  if(myCellsA.indexOf(e.range.getA1Notation())>-1)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Cell G3 requires updating immediately');
    var sht=e.source.getActiveSheet();
    sht.getRange('G3').activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")

Comment: If you trying to run this function without an onEdit trigger then e.source is undefined.

Comment: Current project's triggers: 
customPopUp > From Spreadsheet > On edit

Is what I have selected

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine for me. Try deleting the trigger and reinstalling it.